# How Do I Get Sonarqube to Create Pull Request Comments

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.2

I am using sonar-cube 5.2 with sonar-runner-2.4. I have configured a bitbucket (using mibexsoftware/sonar-bitbucket-plugin) repo, and set this property: sonar.bitbucket.minSeverity=INFO in my local git repo directory.

I can run the analysis, and I do see a Pull Request comment, but the comment is a generic: "SonarQube Analysis reported no issues. Take a chocolate :-)". This really only indicates that my access between sonarqube and bitbucket is correct...

If I go to the sonarqube server, there are several issues identified with my project (a java project). Some are minor, but there is a critical and a major issue.

Based on the documentation, shouldn't some of these issues create Pull Request comments?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pull request analysis is only going to make comments for *new issues* in the code *changed in the PR*

Comment: I am too much of a newbie to rate your answer, but thumbs up! Thanks.

Comment: @DavidMadison you're not too much of a newbie to perhaps accept my answer. :-)

Comment: almost too much of a stackoverflow newbie to accept your answer :)

Comment: I'm getting comments for issues that are not in the PR is there a way to disable this feature ?